# What are some strategies to shrink down a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

What are some strategies to shrink down a model in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO.

Before you start doing anything you should have working specs. If you do not have them, write them first and afterwards spread code into separate files.

One approach is to move code that share a specific usecase into dedicated class (creating invoice, making booking whatever it is in your domain). Sometimes people give those classes Service in name, but it's really up to you as long as you are consequent.
During first step do not refactor code itself, just cut it and move to separate classes so that the model becomes smaller. After any change run tests.

When you complete this phase, then refactor each extracted component keeping SOLID in mind. At this point you should start writing new tests (TDD...)
Also you should start extracting initializing those use cases directly in model - what I want to say is your model should become more and more an object which holds data and something above is aware of context/transactions and pass this model to specific usecases. This will be dificult but really worth your time in the future. At this moment your model should be even smaller because you no longer create and call usecases classes in model but you do it somewhere above.

Comment: I always try to adopt this TDD approach but couldn't. I really want to learn this process.. I don't know how! :/

Comment: Don't feel guilty and don't treat TDD as dogma. I'm aware that in your case it will be difficult, especially when there is so much code to cover. Hovewer you should have at least high level tests (so not unit but integration/acceptance) in order to be sure your code is working after changes. 

On the other hand if it is a long-term project (it seems it is) you should put some effort to guarantee quality by writing specs. 
And lastly if you have 2 options - not write specs at all and write it after the implementation choose the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!  Where in the directory structure would you put those Service classes and how to include them in the model?

Comment: I will answer in that why... It depends. It depends whether code is already structured in more sophisticated way than traditional Rails app or not. Usually Rails app have app/models with a lot of classes and there is not breakdown into more domain specific folders. If it is your case I would suggest app/services.

Comment: @djaszczurowski Yes I do the last one, as with first approach I couldn't write a single bit of code..